# How to Concatenate/Merge Columns from Separate Dataframes with Same Column Names/Location Creating New Frames for Each Column Conatination/Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

So I have two dataframes with the same column names. Like if I two dataframes with 3 columns each, I want to end up with three new dataframes.

Only my dataset is much larger with many more columns and rows. I can always make a unique ID for each data frame. I was thinking a loop but I'm not certain how to even begin with that.

For example:

```
Categorized Dataframe

    DOGS          CATS        BIRDS
    St. Bernard   Tabby       Robin
    Lab           Siamese     Humming
    Pitbull       Hairless    Blue Jay

Numeric Dataframe
    DOGS   CATS  BIRDS
    1      7       3
    5      38      4
    15     17      10
```

After containing or merging, I'd like to end up with

```
    DOGS          DOGS        
    St. Bernard   1       
    Lab           5     
    Pitbull       17    

    CATS        BIRDS
    Tabby       7
    Siamese     38
    Hairless    17

    BIRDS     BIRDS
    Robin     3
    Humming   4
    Blue Jay  10
```

Thanks for your help!

**edit:** I just realized I didn't make it clear thanks @Quang Hoang that I also need to be able to save each frame as separate tables like:

```
DOGS_df = 
    DOGS          DOGS        
    St. Bernard   1       
    Lab           5     
    Pitbull       17    
CATS_df = 
    CATS        BIRDS
    Tabby       7
    Siamese     38
    Hairless    17
BIRDS_df = 
    BIRDS     BIRDS
    Robin     3
    Humming   4
    Blue Jay  10
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do so, but here's a solution `for col in categories.columns: print(pd.concat((categories[col], numerica[col]), axis=1))`.

Comment: hi--that helps! Thanks. Just as a follow up and I'll add it above, I need to save each concated frame as it's own thing. Like Dogs = pd.concat([DOGS_x, DOGS_y]), if I were doing it the long way.

Comment: do a list comprehension: `{col: df.conat(...) for  col in categories.columns}`.

Comment: Hi--sorry about poking you again
But when I do this
 '{col: pd.concat((Cat_Key[col], Num_Key[col]), axis=1) for col in Cat_Key.columns}', 
and then if I try to call DOG, I get an error. I think I may implementing your solution wrong.